# how to use if let synatx on an AtomicOption

Tags: rust

Is it possible to only read data from an AtomicOption if there exists some data.

```
use atomic_option::AtomicOption;

fn print(a: &AtomicOption<f64>) {
    if let Some(data) = a {
        println!("{}", data);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: AtomicOption<f64> = AtomicOption::empty();
    print(&a);
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src\main.rs:4:12
  |
4 |     if let Some(data) = a {
  |            ^^^^^^^^^^   - this expression has type `&AtomicOption<f64>`
  |            |
  |            expected `AtomicOption<f64>`, found `Option<_>`
  |
  = note: expected struct `AtomicOption<f64>`
               found enum `Option<_>`
```

Comment: `Some` is a constructor for `Option` not `AtomicOption`. It looks like you need to call `take` and match the result of that e.g. `if let Some(data) = a.take(Ordering::SeqCst) { ... }`

Comment: but `take` sets the `AtomicOption` to `None` which I don't want that to happen. I just want to read the data that's present

Comment: If concurrent access to this data is essential, and you need to read without modifying, you might need a more complex synchronization mechanism or a different atomic type that better suits your needs.

Comment: Note: [`atomic_option` is **unsound**](https://github.com/reem/rust-atomic-option/issues/3).

Comment: I would recommend using [`AtomicCell`](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/latest/crossbeam/atomic/struct.AtomicCell.html) and using a sentinel value like `NaN` to represent the `None` case.